# What would cause IMultisearchResponse's ConnectionStatus.Request to be null?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

I'm cross posting this question from an issue I made on [Github](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/issues/1201).

I am trying to log the requests I am making to better debug some internal issues, and apparently after performing an `var results = await _client.MultiSearchAsync(...)`, sometimes `results.ConnectionStatus.Request` comes back as null.

I am attempting to figure out what would cause this; potentially, it does not appear to happen with any sort of consistency.